# PyPlot in Juno: Fixing axis height

Tags: matplotlib, plot, julia

I apologise if this has already been asked, I've searched long and hard on this site and couldn't find anything that worked. I'm using Julia, specifically the Juno IDE, and I am trying to use PyPlot to create my graphs. I wanted to set the y axis height when plotting, but leave the x axis variable. Here is the code I have been using to generate my plots

```
fig = figure()
ax = fig[:add_axes]
BEFE250 = (plot(s1, s2, lw=1.0, "-", color="b"))

ylabel("u(x,t)", size=20)
xlabel("t", size=20)

gcf()
```

which gives me

[image: Reflection]

However, I need space in the top left corner as I am going to layer another picture on top in latex. So I need to set the y-axis height to between -3 and 3. However, if I set the axes height in PyPlot

```
fig = figure()
ax = fig[:add_axes]([0.1, 0.1, -3.0, 3.0])
BEFE250 = (plot(s1, s2, lw=1.0, "-", color="b"))

ylabel("u(x,t)", size=20)
xlabel("t", size=20)

gcf()
```

then it switches the orientation of the x-axis. If I set the axis height after running the plot, PyPlot puts the picture in a box in a legend off to the side of the main picture, and the main picture is empty? If someone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**: Using xlim=(-10.,10.) and ylim=(-2.,12.) doesn't work either. PyPlot still adapts the axes to the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `xlim(-10, 10)` and `ylim(-2, 12)` after the `plot` command:

```
plot(s1, s2, lw=1.0, "-", color="b")
ylim(-3, 3)
```

Just try this, without the `add_axes`.

You probably also want LaTeX labels -- just add an `L` before the string, which gives a special LaTeX string from the `LaTeXString` package. You can either just add the `L`, or add `$` inside too:

```
ylabel(L"u(x,t)", size=20)
ylabel(L"$u(x,t)$", size=20)
```

[The `$` are necessary in certain circumstances that I forget.]

I'm not sure how good the PyPlot support is in Juno.
You might want to try this in IJulia.

By the way, is there a reason you want to layer on a separate figure in LaTeX? That might not be the best way to do it.